# Force an array to recalcuate length after sort

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If you take an array and do the following:

```
arr = [];
arr[100] = 1;
```

The length will be 101, which makes sense due to 0-99 being set as `undefined`

Now if we sort that array: `arr.sort()` it will look like this: `[1, undefined x100]` since keys are not preserved. However, the length is still 101, since the `undefined` have all been moved to the end, instead of removed.

Is this behavior intentional and if so: is there a built-in function that removes `undefined` and recalculates and why is it intentional?

I am **not** asking how to write my own function to recalculate length. A sorted array's length can easily be forced with `for (x = 0; arr[x] != undefined; x++);arr.length = x;`

Comment: Why would sorting remove elements?

Comment: @DaveNewton Since sorting acknowledges that they aren't defined, why would it keep them? Is there some other function that can be applied after sorting that would remove them?

Comment: If you have an array of a given length, and you sort it, I don't understand the idea of getting back something if a different length.

Comment: @Rhyono—the function at the end will remove members with value of `null` and `undefined` (i.e. they exist with a value of `undefined`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> arr = [];
> arr[100] = 1;

> The length will be 101, which makes sense due to 0-99 being set as undefined
```

The array has only one member at 100, it is like:

```
var arr = { '100': 1, 'length': 101};
```

> Now if we sort that array: arr.sort() it will look like this: [1, undefined x100]

No, it doesn't. It has one member at 0 and a length of 100. There aren't 100 members with a value of 'undefined'.

If you wish to reduce the array to only the defined members, there is no built–in function to do that (i.e. essentially to set the *length* to the highest index that has a value).

You can only do that by iterating over the array, e.g. by reducing the length from the right until an existing property is reached:

```
function trimArray(arr) {
  var i = arr.length;
  while ( !(--i in arr)) {
    arr.length -= 1;
  } 
}
```

Note that for the above to work properly, the array must be sorted. Also, it modifies the array passed in.

Here's a way to extend Array.prototype with a compress method so an array exists of only the defined members and the length is reset appropriately:

```
if (!('compress' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.compress = function() {

    var i = 0,
        lastExisting = 0,
        len = this.length;

    do {

      if (i in this) {
        this[lastExisting++] = this[i];
      }
    } while (++i < len)

    this.length = lastExisting; 
  }
}
```

Note that it will not remove members whose value is *undefined*, only those that don't exists at all. So:

```
var x = [,,,,1,,,2];
x[20] = void 0;

x.compress()

alert(x + '\n' + x.length); // [1,2,<undefined>], length = 3
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by zzzzBov, this can also be done using `filter`:

```
var x = x.filter(function(item){return true;});
```

which will replace `x` with a new array of only the defined members regardless of their value. It will be non-sparse (or contiguous) and have an appropriate length, e.g.

```
var x = [,,,,1,,,2];
x[20] = void 0;  // set x[20] to undefined, length is 21

x = x.filter(function(item){return true;});  // [2, 3, <undefined>], length = 3
```

Note that this method will only update the array referenced by x, it will not update any other reference to the same array, e.g.

```
 var x = [,,1];
 var y = x;  // x and y reference same array

 x = x.filter(function(item){return true}); // x is now another array of members
                                            // filtered from the original array

 alert(x); // [1] x references a different array
 alert(y); // [,,1] y still references the original array
```

this may be useful behaviour if there is a requirement to keep the original array. In contrast, the `compress` method modifies the original array:

```
 var x = [,,1];
 var y = x;  // x and y reference same array

 x.compress();

 alert(x); // [1] x is a modified version of the original array
 alert(y); // [1] y references the same (original) array
```

I have no idea if there is an intention to add such a method to `Array.prototype` in future versions of ECMAScript or what it might be called, so a different name might be advisable, say `xcompress` or similar, to avoid unintended conflict with future versions and to make it obvious that it's a native method, not built–in.

I'm also a bit stumped for a suitable name, since *packed* and *compressed* already have defined meanings that are different to *non–contiguous*, but that seems unwieldy so it's *compress* for now.

Comment: I'm using Chrome (as per the tag) and according to the developer console: here's the exact output of an array `[1, 10, 10, 2, undefined × 96]`

Comment: @Rhyono, that's due to the way the developer console displays array data. If you use `arr.hasOwnProperty(10)` you should get `false`, as it doesn't actually have that property set.

Comment: @Rhyono Remember, "arrays" in JavaScript aren't like arrays in Java or C.

Comment: @zzzzBov That's what I was looking for. That's also why I specifically said "chrome" in the tag because it didn't make sense for it to actually define all of those as undefined, but since it was just how it represents it: it's understandable.

Comment: @Rhyono, firebug in firefox also displays many listings of `undefined`, as an unset property will return `undefined` (ex. `a={}; a[100];//undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [];
arr[100] = 1;
```

The code won't set `0-99` to `undefined`, which it does is only set the key `100` to `1`, and `length` property to `101`.

And `Array.sort` won't change the property `length` of an array.

After sort, there are two own properties of `arr`, `0` is `1`, and `length` is still `101`.

[image]

Comment: Up to a length of 100, it represents it differently. That was what threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get around the issue, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array once you've sorted it (or filter it before sorting).

```
var arr;
arr = [];
arr[100] = 1;
arr.sort();
arr = arr.filter(function (item) {
    return typeof item !== 'undefined';
});
```

What's actually happening is that you're overriding the `length` property, which is used by the `Array` object to determine where the end of the array is, whether or not the array has that many properties.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking.  They state they already know how to do the above.

Comment: @zzzzBov—the function should be `var y = x.filter(function (item) {return item;});` since only members that exist will be visited. Your function will remove existing members whose value is `undefined`.

Comment: @RobG, not sure what API you're referencing, but ["`filter` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a `true` value"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). If `return item;` were used, falsey values would be removed from the array.

Comment: @zzzzBov—yes, you're right. The filter function should return `true` so that all defined properties are retained (including those with falsey values such as `undefined`, `false`, `0`, etc.).